# ruby split string by repeating characters or a space

Tags: ruby, regex

How do i split this string.

```
"6885558 8866887777" => ["6", "88", "555", "8", "88", "66", "88", "7777"]
```

I tried this, but it never worked.

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :020 > "111133".split(/(\d)\1+/)
 => ["", "1", "", "3"]
```

Comment: I don't think a `split` method would work, as these remove the characters that are matched by `split`. I think you may need to iterate over the string instead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`split` will just use whatever it matches as a delimiter, removing it from the string in question. What you're looking for is [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
str = "6885558 8866887777"
str.scan(/((\d)\2*)/).map(&:first)
# => ["6", "88", "555", "8", "88", "66", "88", "7777"]
```

Taking it slow, the `\d` matches any digit. It's in the second capturing group, so `\2*` then matches any further occurrences of the same digit. This produces an array that looks like

```
[["6", "6"], ["88", "8"], ["555", "5"], ["8", "8"],
 ["88", "8"], ["66", "6"], ["88", "8"], ["7777", "7"]]
```

Since we only want the first item in each of those sub arrays, we can collect them all with `map(&:first)`.

(Note that `str.scan(/(\d)\1*/)` would simply produce an array out of the first capturing group, which means we'd only get one digit from a sequence of possibly repeated numbers.)