# Check whether a string contains all the characters of another string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Let's say I have a string, like `string= "aasmflathesorcerersnstonedksaottersapldrrysaahf"`. If you haven't noticed, you can find the phrase `"harry potter and the sorcerers stone"` in there (minus the space).

I need to check whether `string` contains all the elements of the string.

```
string.include? ("sorcerer") #=> true
string.include? ("harrypotterandtheasorcerersstone") #=> false, even though it contains all the letters to spell harrypotterandthesorcerersstone
```

Include does not work on shuffled string.

How can I check if a string contains all the elements of another string?

Comment: Please edit to clarify two points. 1. For `string` to include "sorcerer", must `string` contain at least three "r"s? 2. Why does your second example return `false`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think he is showing how Ruby's `include?` works, and the `false` result is undesirable. I think the question is how to insure that both cases return `true`.

Comment: PS: If you're going to use parentheses with your method calls (and quite often they're necessary), be careful with your spaces: `m(x, y)` is fine but `m (x, y)` is a syntax error. Your `string.include? ("sorcerer")` works fine because there's only one argument so your grouping-parentheses still form a valid expression.

Comment: Hi Cary, meagar is right. It's like a version of include that works with shuffled string. Therefore, `sorcerer` must contain however many `r`'s the word `sorcerer` actually has!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sets and array intersection don't account for repeated chars, but a [histogram / frequency counter](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/Enumerable%3Afrequency) does:

```
require 'facets'

s1 = "aasmflathesorcerersnstonedksaottersapldrrysaahf"
s2 = "harrypotterandtheasorcerersstone"
freq1 = s1.chars.frequency
freq2 = s2.chars.frequency
freq2.all? { |char2, count2| freq1[char2] >= count2 } 
#=> true
```

Write your own `Array#frequency` if you don't want to the facets dependency.

```
class Array
  def frequency
    Hash.new(0).tap { |counts| each { |v| counts[v] += 1 } }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I presume that if the string to be checked is "sorcerer", `string` must include, for example, three "r"'s. If so you could use the method [Array#difference](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11815), which I've proposed be added to the Ruby core.

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end 

str = "aasmflathesorcerersnstonedksaottersapldrrysaahf"

target = "sorcerer"
target.chars.difference(str.chars).empty?
  #=> true

target = "harrypotterandtheasorcerersstone"
target.chars.difference(str.chars).empty?
  #=> true
```

If the characters of target must not only be in `str`, but must be in the same order, we could write:

```
target = "sorcerer" 
r = Regexp.new "#{ target.chars.join "\.*" }"
  #=> /s.*o.*r.*c.*e.*r.*e.*r/ 
str =~ r
  #=> 2 (truthy)
```

(or `!!(str =~ r) #=> true`)

```
target = "harrypotterandtheasorcerersstone"
r = Regexp.new "#{ target.chars.join "\.*" }"
  #=>  /h.*a.*r.*r.*y* ... o.*n.*e/
str =~ r
  #=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

A different albeit not necessarily better solution using sorted character arrays and sub-strings:

Given your two strings...

```
subject = "aasmflathesorcerersnstonedksaottersapldrrysaahf"
search = "harrypotterandthesorcerersstone"
```

You can sort your subject string using `.chars.sort.join`...

```
subject = subject.chars.sort.join # => "aaaaaaacddeeeeeffhhkllmnnoooprrrrrrssssssstttty"
```

And then produce a list of substrings to search for:

```
search = search.chars.group_by(&:itself).values.map(&:join)
# => ["hh", "aa", "rrrrrr", "y", "p", "ooo", "tttt", "eeeee", "nn", "d", "sss", "c"]
```

You could alternatively produce the same set of substrings using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292338/ruby-split-string-by-repeating-characters-or-a-space)

```
search = search.chars.sort.join.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map(&:first)
```

And then simply check whether every search sub-string appears within the sorted subject string:

```
search.all? { |c| subject[c] }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a 2 dimensional array out of your `string` letter bank, to associate the count of letters to each letter.
2. Create a 2 dimensional array out of the harry potter string in the same way.
3. Loop through both and do comparisons.

I have no experience in Ruby but this is how I would start to tackle it in the language I know most, which is Java.